# Divisors of a number in a given range

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, factoring, computational-mathematics

I'm working on a problem and wondered if there was a clever way to do it. The general form of the problem is like this: given $\ell_1,\ell_2,$ and $N$, find all divisors $d$ of $N$ with $\ell_1\le d\le\ell_2.$ I have the full factorization of $N$, which is much larger than $\ell_2.$ Also the number of divisors of $N$ is much larger than $\ell_2$: in my case $\Omega(N)=932=\omega(N).$

Right now I'm solving it by brute force: loop from $\ell_1$ to $\ell_2$ and test if the number divides $N.$ But surely there's a better way!

Comment: $\Omega(N)=932=\omega(N)$ suggests that $N$ is square-free and is the product of $932$ distinct prime numbers, making it bigger than $10^{3128}$.  How big are $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$? $\Omega(N)=932=\omega(N)$

Comment: @Henry: In my case $N\approx10^{3460}$, $\ell_1\approx2\cdot10^{17}$, and $\ell_2\approx3\cdot10^{19}.$ But I'd be interested in a nontrivial answer even if it didn't work with these particular numbers.